# Overcrowding vinca leaves. Any idea?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, indoors

I have a pot of vinca I took inside for winter.  It receives light from aero garden (which I’m not using to grow herbs right now) and indoor temperature is about 70-74 degrees.

[image]

I’m noticing that while flowers keep blooming great the leaves are growing so close together (see photo) and no room to breathe.  How can I grow them with ample space between leaves? Cut off stem?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: That plant looks fine; typically, small internodes (space between leaves on a stem) mean that the plant is getting plenty of light. This is the opposite of a plant being "leggy". Personally, I would do nothing to this plant except occasional fertilization.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I had no idea it meant they were receiving plenty of light!

Comment: I would appreciate a more detailed(and perhaps more generic) answer to this question. The leaves cover each other so many of them seem to contribute nothing to photosynthesis. Furthermore they trap moisture perhaps inviting fungal diseases. Plus they obscure visual inspection of the stems. Those are all speculation on my part and would love to have them acknowledged or dismissed.